# Telebot import issue

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

When I'm trying to import telebot it gives me the error.
**Error:**

[image]

I've tried to reinstall `telegramBotApi` several times but it didn't work out.

Comment: Have you uninstalled ```telebot``` itself? This helped me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Telebot associated with `pyTelegramBotAPI` not `telegramBotApi`.

Run this : `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`